# Jhipster - connecting two applications to one database

Tags: jhipster

I have a working Jhipster application, linked to a mysql database.
I would like to create a new application that I would connect to the first application database.

Is it possible? regarding to liquibase/entities/etc.

Comment: Is y9our question about jhipster or liquibase? Have you tried, what are you specific concerns.  In general yes, applications can share a database, but need to be orchestrated to work in cooperation.  Liquibase provides a locking mechanism to support this so many instances can connect, and only 1 will modify.

Comment: it's about how jhipster configures the application. I assume common application entities must be exactly the same in the two applications?

Answer (score 4):

Why should this not be possible? MySQL itself is a multiuser DBMS, so it could handle multiple connections.

The only problem would be liquibase, because it checks if your database is valid against your changelogs. So, if your second app also uses liquibase and has not the same changelogs with same checksums, it will not start. So your second app should not use liquibase and you should remove the liquibase-stuff from the second app. The means: the first app is repsponsible for creating/updating the schema using liquibase and the second app just uses the same schema.

And you're right: the entities must be the same, because hibernate/JPA assumes the same column and entity/table names (which are given by the database)...

In my opinion, a better approach would be the microservice-way: the first application is the only who access the database directly and offers some interfaces for the entities via REST. Then, your second application simply uses the interface via a REST-Client. This also allows you to define other/modified entities via the REST-Service and your second app may not use exactly the same like in the first application.

Comment: This is the correct answer : use SOA/micro-services. You will run into troubles with hibernate cache if you modify the DB without going through it. As for Liquibase, don't remove code : use the `no-liquibase` profile to deactivate it.

Comment: Tangential question, can't seem to find an answer online. Is it possible 2 have 2 users in one app config, one to exclusively run Liquibase and the other exclusively to read/write? I cannot for the life of me find this, and it should be possible.

Comment: Are you talking about db-users?! Normally, there is only one user, which comes from the config (application.yml) and is part of the "primary" `DataSource`, which in turn is used by the `LiquibaseAutoConfiguration` and is also used by JPA etc.
But, it's possible to configure multiple data sources and you can create a bean for a second data source and annotate it with `@LiquibaseDataSource` so that liquibase uses this one and not the primary (https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html#howto-execute-liquibase-database-migrations-on-startup)